# How to specity image url received in a component using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am working on this app, where my card component receives props. One of them is the img prop which contains the local file url. But as my card component is inside a folder it demands specific address of the file.

What should I do?

I tried :

```
export default function Card(props) {
    return (
        <div className="card">

            // This ofcourse doesn't work because this isn't the absolute path. Like I have to include ../images/imgUrl
            <img src={props.img} className="card--image" />
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to import the image from local folder (must be inside your project)? `import myImg from "path/to/img"`

Comment: I have but how do i specify the absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

/images/image/`${props.img}`

Minor bug.